# Marklogic Java Client API criteria not working

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-9

I am looking to get all documents in a collection having a particular term present in the document.
So, I am making use of the following code construct:

```
StringQueryDefinition sqd = queryManager.newStringDefinition();
sqd.setCollections(collectionName);
sqd.setCriteria(searchTerm);
```

but I am always getting the result count as 0, though if I remove the criteria, then I am getting all the documents in the collection.

What is wrong with this approach, please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally was able to find the answer with tags related to namespace constraint:

```java
//Create options for search:
String options= "<search:options xmlns:search='http://marklogic.com/appservices/search'>"+
"<search:constraint name='constraintname'>"+
"<search:value>"+
"<search:element name='elementname' ns='your-namespace'/>"+
"</search:value>"+
"</search:constraint>"+
"</search:options>";

//Write options to database
QueryOptionsManager optionsManager = client.newServerConfigManager().newQueryOptionsManager();
StringHandle writeHandle = new StringHandle(options);
optionsManager.writeOptions("OPTION_NAME", writeHandle);

//Create StructuredQueryBuilder with the options
StructuredQueryBuilder queryBuilder = queryManager.newStructuredQueryBuilder("OPTIONS_NAME");

//Create StructuredQueryDefinition using the query builder and specify constraint name and value.
StructuredQueryDefinition queryDefinition = queryBuilder.and(queryBuilder.valueConstraint("constraintname", value));
queryDefinition.setCollections(collectionName);

SearchHandle searchHandle = queryManager.search(queryDefinition, new SearchHandle());
```